# Is there any minimal distance recommendation between two USB female ports?

Tags: usb

Is there any minimal distance recommendation between two USB_A female ports? Between USB_A port and other elements?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at your collection of USB memory sticks and you'll find that some are very wide - much wider than a standard plug. If you want to cater for those ...

Comment: AFAIK, there is such a requirement in the USB standard, but I don't have access to it now. At the very minimum, it is twice the width of an A plug's over mold.

Comment: Many times connector spacing is determines by human factor engineering (yes, there is such a discipline).  Considerations include ease of gasping a connector with fingers and  room to use a tool (though this is not an issue with USB connectors).

Comment: Try fitting a few of these [USB load testers](https://www.elektormagazine.com/assets/upload/img/public/original/200049-008-94-original-jt-hd35-info.jpg)!

Answer (score 8):

The last mechanical specification, [USB 3.1 Legacy Cable and Connector specification](https://usb.org/document-library/usb-31-legacy-cable-and-connector-revision-10) does not seem to mention a minimum distance between receptacles.

It does specify a maximum overmold width for Type A plugs of 16 mm.
However, as you may have found out, thumb drives do not follow this...

Comment: Thanks for reference. Seems that 16x8 mm is maximum for mold size.

Answer (score 2):

No, there aren't any minimal distances to comply to.

It's up to the product designer and common sense rules.

Comment: Yeah, it would be embarrassing if two cables wouldn't fit at the same time because of connector shrouds.